# Securing communication between multiplatform clients (Desktop and Android primarily) with desktop server through SSL/TLS

Tags: java, android, ssl, tcp, udp

I went through the JSSE Reference Guide + Stack Overflow most common explanations about SSL/TLS and I haven't really found anything that encapsulates everything what I need.

The project that I'm currently working on is about connecting multiplatform clients (**Android** or **Desktop**) on a desktop server which is connected to the robot (it is working in the local network which has parallel **TCP and UDP connection** -> **TCP** is used for sending some kind of commands for the robot from the client to the server and **UDP** is used for updating the robot position on the map which is sent from the server to the client).

Maybe I was a little half-cocked so I tried to implement the Android piece of code without really informing myself about everything that possibly could go wrong. The code below represents the code on the server side (which is desktop application) and client side (android application).

**Server:**

```
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keystore.load(new FileInputStream(PATH_TO_KEYSTORE), PASSWORD.toCharArray());

        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        kmf.init(keystore, PASSWORD.toCharArray());

        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        KeyManager[] keyManagers = kmf.getKeyManagers();

        context.init(keyManagers, null, null);

        SSLServerSocketFactory factory = context.getServerSocketFactory();

        serverSocket = (SSLServerSocket) factory.createServerSocket(port);
        serverSocket.setSoTimeout(0);
```

**Android client:**

```
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keystore.load(Gdx.files.internal(PATH_TO_KEYSTORE).read(), PASSWORD.toCharArray());

        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        tmf.init(keystore);

        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        TrustManager[] trustManagers = tmf.getTrustManagers();

        context.init(null, trustManagers, null);

        SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = context.getSocketFactory();

        sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(address, port);
```

Variable ***PATH_TO_KEYSTORE*** is a path to the file which was generated using this command `keytool -genkey -keystore server.keystore`. I know that I shouldn't have the same keystore for server and client, but I don't know how can I do it the other way which is one of my questions too.

After executing this piece of code, exception happened which said **Wrong version of key store.** and then I figured out that I am totally lost.

Anyway, I have several questions that bother me in this matter:

1. Is it possible to secure communication both for **TCP and UDP** using the **SSL/TLS**?
2. Is it possible to create a uniform way to **generate keystores** that will work for every platform (since I figured out on an example above that Android does not support JKS)?
3. If the answer on question No. 2. is **NO**, how can I secure the communication in separate ways (how to generate keystores for Android and Desktop version separately)?
4. When everything works out like it should (in a static way), is there a way to generate keystore for client dynamically, in other words: how can one generate his private key in the Android piece of code (which ultimately means that every client will have its own generated private key)?